# Querying OData api from Redux

Tags: odata, breeze, redux, olingo

I have a Web API using OData that I need to query.  The client application is a SPA built with React/Redux, but it looks as if most data service libraries such as isomorphic-fetch do not support OData.  Can BreezeJS be useful for me in this situation?  Or OLingo's ODataJs? Any examples, tutorials, resources on using these or any other OData clients with Redux?  AFAIK, I just need a the client library to query an OData source and support promises.  And as far as the data I get back from the server, I just need simple json objects;  no need for models that support binding.

I've seen discussions of Breeze + Angular/Backbone, but can it support Redux/React?

I doubt that either Breeze or ODataJS supports ES6, so if i had to wrap them in a ES6 module, would they still function properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it helps if you consider that OData isn't that far off from REST. If it's just about pulling the data from a OData service, you won't need much more than `jQuery.getJSON` and Breeze will work too. However, if you want to do it the fancy way, and want you app to introspect the meta-model and such, you should have a look at datajs or olingo.